# Realloc with matrix and automatization

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, malloc, realloc

I was wondering why realloc for a char* or whatever 1D array works if I do something like
oldpointer=realloc(oldpointer,newsize);

But when I try with a 2D char* array it fails.
Looking here and there I see that sometimes people use 
NewPointer=realloc(oldpointer,newsize) but if it's the only use it will not be useful to me, since I need to resize the matrix' columns and rows often, in a loop (I must fill an array of strings without knowing first how many string I will insert nor the size of each one)

the code I used for trying is this,

```
void main(){
    int max = 5, i,j;
    char **matrix;
    matrix=malloc(max*sizeof(char));
    for(i=0;i<max;i++){
        matrix[i]=malloc(max*sizeof(char));

    }
    matrix=realloc(matrix,max*2*sizeof(char));

    strcpy(matrix[4],"we\0");
    printf("%s",matrix[4]);

}
```

Error in `./out': realloc(): invalid next size: 0x00000000015c4010 ***
Aborted

Comment: This is a bad `realloc()` -> `matrix=realloc(matrix,max*2*sizeof(char));
` in case of failure you can't do anything to recover. Also, `"we\0"` is absolutely unnecessary, `"we"` is enough. Ans `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition.

Comment: To my understanding, the first `malloc` does not work as expected. Shouldn't it be `matrix = malloc(max*sizeof(char*))`?

Comment: @Codor yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your double pointer can't hold pointers because you did not allocate enough space.

```
matrix = malloc(max * sizeof(char));
/* which is exactly the same as
 * matrix = malloc(max);
 */
```

should be

```
matrix = malloc(max * sizeof(char *));
/*                        ^ max pointers, so sizeof a poitner */
```

then if you want to `realloc()`, you can do it like this

```
void *pointer;

pointer = realloc(matrix, 2 * max * sizeof(char *));
if (poitner == NULL)
    handleFailure_OrExit_ButDoNot_Use_The_Realloced_Poitner();
matrix = pointer;
```

**Always** check the return value of a function if it returns one, for example `malloc()`/`calloc()`/`realloc()` "*and any custom implementation normally*", return `NULL` on failure.

Answer (score 0):

First your `matrix` is an array of `char*`, so you should be allocating:

```
matrix=malloc(max * sizeof(char*));
```

Likewise for the `realloc()`.

You also don't need `"we\0"`, `"we"` would suffice. All strings in double quotes are `NUL` terminating string literals. Allocate enough memory for each of `char*`s and the `char`s and you should be good.